# Database selection for text field search

Tags: database, postgresql, indexing, sql-like, text-search

I've `2.5` Millions records (can be more) and I want to search on  `title` field. Data is basically in Postgres database. So when I do search with `LIKE` operator using wildcard character like `where title LIKE '%some_string%'` it is slow. I did some research and found that adding an index on that field will only help if you don't have `%` sign in the beginning. So my plan is to choose a database which supports fast text search in a field. So I need your suggestions and guidance to choose the database which fits best in my scenario. I can even choose some NoSQL database if it provides better performance. ElasticSearch and Solr are not the options that I can choose. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not Solr / Elastic? They are "some NoSQL database", and they can handle easily this scenario.

Comment: @alehoss This is just requirement. I tried Solr but I've limited memory on server.

Comment: Have you tried the Postgres's full text search data types? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/datatype-textsearch.html and https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/textsearch.html

Comment: Upvoting the suggestion for postgres full text search, it should work. If you want faster full text without the hassle of java, try xapian, it has good python bindings.

Comment: use FTS with GIN on title attribute